# How to get the root element of the current instance of a Livewire component?

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire

According to the official [Livewire docs on inline scripts](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/inline-scripts#accessing-javascript-component-instance), it's possible to get the current instance of a Livewire component inside the inline scripts of their views by using `@this` directive.

As the documentation points out,

> *Note: the `@this` directive compiles to the following string for JavaScript to interpret: "Livewire.find([component-id])".*

It mentions nothing else about retrieval of the component ID itself, or the root element.

In my effort to find the answer, I've stumbled upon [this file](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/blob/master/src/Component.php) in Livewire's source code, which proves that there indeed is a public property `id` in Livewire components. However, logging `@this.id` into the console on `livewire:load` event in the following way:

```
document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
    console.log(@this.id);
});
```

will output to the console the following:

[image: Console output for this.id]

Logging `@this.get('id')` in the same place will return `null`, so I guess I am doing something wrong.

How to retrieve that ID by using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

This is how to retrieve both the instance ID and the root element as a DOM node.

```
var instanceID          = @this.__instance.id; // The unique ID of the instance. 
var instanceRootElement = @this.__instance.el; // The root DOM node of the instance.
```

### Why It Works

[Here](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/blob/e117c78f9a4b19edb294b5b576138fd1f896925a/js/index.js) in the Livewire class declaration, there is a method `find` that is executed when we use `@this` directive, according to Livewire documentation on inline scripts referred in the question. The return value of the method is not the component class itself, but its `$wire` property.

The getter for this `$wire` property can be examined [here](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/blob/master/js/component/index.js) in the Component class declaration. It utilizes the [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object to intercept some of the properties and process them correctly. Among the intercepted properties is the `__instance` property, which returns the component's instance itself. From there, we can directly access all its properties and methods, including `el` for the root DOM node and `id` for the unique identifier of the component.

Judging by the underscores before the property, this `__instance` property is reserved for internal usage, but this currently is the only way to access these properties from inline scripts.

Answer (score 0):

In the view,
you can get the component id as: `{{ $this->id }}` (the `$this` is important, `$id` directly doesn't work), so in javascript,

```
var idEl = "{{ $this->id }}";
```

you can get the root element:

```
var RootEl = document.querySelector('[wire\\:id="{{ $this->id }}"]') );
```